# CLR_SEMAPHORE & CXPACKET wait types

Tags: sql-server

I ran sp_Blitzfirst, and it threw back CXPACKET and CLR_SEMAPHORE waits as the top waits for my SQL server.

I know how to fix CXPACKET waits, but how do I go about fixing CLR_semaphore waits?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore that wait type `CLR_semaphore` - its a benign wait type to be filtered out as per [Wait statistics, or please tell me where it hurts](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/)